# How to add external C++ library in Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

Not able to add external C++ library folders in cpp folder.
How do i mention the folders to be included in CMakeLists.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

```
file(GLOB CPP_FILES "*.cpp")

add_library( 
    SHARED
    ${CPP_FILES}
)
```

add this to your CMakeLists.txt.

It should now add files from the cpp folder to your project.

Comment: I have made the suggested change but still it does not show up the folders in the cpp folder.

Comment: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
file(GLOB CPP_FILES "*.cpp")
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib
             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED
             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             ${CPP_FILES})
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib
              log )
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       ${log-lib} )`

Comment: Not sure then, hopefully someone else has a better idea.

Comment: _"but still it does not show up the folders in the cpp folder"_ I find it unclear exactly what you're looking for. Is the problem that the build fails, or that you can't see the external files in the project view in Android Studio?